# How do you get the asp:Menu to follow the url provided in the Web.sitemap?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I have a simple `asp:menu-item` that uses the `Web.sitemap` to get the menu items. The page will postback but fails to get the page associated to the clicked item. I will mention that the navigation bar code is within the masterpage file.

```
<div>
  <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1"  ShowStartingNode="false" runat="server" />
  <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" Orientation="horizontal"  runat="server" BackColor="#a0a080" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
      DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#a00000"
      StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Style="z-index: 2; left: 390px; position: absolute;
      top: 281px" Height="20px" Width="311px">
      <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#a0a080" />
      <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
      <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#a0a080" ForeColor="White" />
      <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#a0a080" />
      <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#a0a080" />
      <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
      <DataBindings>
          <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SiteMapNode" EnabledField="Title" TextField="Title" />
      </DataBindings>
      <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" />
  </asp:Menu>
</div>    

<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >  
  <siteMapNode url="" title=""  description="">  
    <siteMapNode title="Home"  description="Zombie (be)Warehouse" url="index.aspx" />  
    <siteMapNode title="Armor" description="Anti-Zombie Armor" url="Armor.aspx" />  
    <siteMapNode title="Weapons" description="Anti-Zombie Weapons" url="Weapons.aspx" />  
    <siteMapNode title="Manuals" description="Survival Manuals" url="Manuals.aspx" />  
    <siteMapNode title="Sustenance" description="Prepared food for survival" url="Sustenance.aspx" />  
    <siteMapNode title="Contacts"  description="Contact Us"  url="Contacts.aspx" />  
    <siteMapNode title="About" description="About Zombie (be)Warehouse" url="About.aspx" />  
  </siteMapNode>  
</siteMap>
```

**Update:**
The problem is being found in the `DataBindings` section of the menu item. Notice the line:

```
<asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SiteMapNode" EnabledField="Title" Text="Title" />
```

The `Text="Title"` sets the menu's displayed text from the `Web.sitemap`'s text field. I noticed that the `MenuItemBinding` item had a field called `NavigateUrlField`.

So to solve this issue, you simple need to change/add to the `asp:MenuItemBinding`

```
<asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SiteMapNode" NavigateUrlField="url" EnabledField="Title" TextField="Title" />
```

Comment: So it sounds as though you issue is resolved? If so, nice work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `NavigateUrlField` field to the `MenuItemBinding` like this   `<asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SiteMapNode" EnabledField="Title" TextField="Title" NavigateUrlField="url"/>`